# Optimizing database query in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have 4 models

```rb
module Vehicle
  has_many :routes
end

module Route
  has_many :route_users
  belongs_to :vehicle
end

module RouteUser
  belongs_to :route
  belongs_to :user
end

module User
  belongs_to :route_user
end
```

My goal is to return the most recent driver (a `user`) through the `aggregate.rb`; to be specific, I need user `id, first_name, last_name`.

```rb
 
  attributes = {
    id: vehicle.id,
    ... other attributes ...
  }

  attributes.merge!(
    driver: {
      id: vehicle.routes.last.route_users.last.user.id,
      first_name: vehicle.routes.last.route_users.last.user.first_name,
      last_name: vehicle.routes.last.route_users.last.user.last_name
    }
  ) if vehicle.routes.present? && vehicle.routes.last.route_users.present?
```

As you can see, `.merge!` loads a bunch of information and dramatically slows down the `aggregate.rb` return. Is there any way to optimize this return to make it faster? Am I missing something?

Comment: Hi Anton, can you add `ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)` in your code before the merge, and add the return for us in your question to help us analyse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can improve your User model to make the query easier.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :route_users
  has_many :routes, through: :route_users
  has_many :vehicles, through: :routes
end
```

And when the query is big from one side, the best way is two invert the logic, and make a query from user, example:

First fetch last_user_drive, and after that, use his fields to merge into attributes

```
last_user_driver = User.joins(routes: :vehicle).where(vehicle: {id: vehicle.id}).order('routes.created_at').last

...
attributes.merge!(
  driver: {
    id: last_user_driver.id,
    first_name: last_user_driver.first_name,
    last_name: last_user_driver.last_name
  }
) if last_user_driver.present?
```

Comment: It seems that the solution does make sense; getting the following error: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying = uuid
LINE 1: ...NER JOIN "route_users" ON "route_users"."user_id" = "users"....
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.`

Comment: @AntonS. I create my test models with this following commands, maybe we have differents fks, can you send your schema for this models?
`rails g model Vehicle`
`rails g model Route vehicle:references`
`rails g model User`
`rails g model RouteUser route:references user:references`

Comment: It works! The code I posted was oversimplified, which is my fault; Some tables use `UUIDs`, some `IDs`. Your solution works, thank you very much!